# Wget: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: raspberry-pi, wget

Whenever I try to download anything with wget I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` with or without -c it doesn't matter.

I have tried this in both Ubuntu mate on my Raspberry pi 3 and arch Linux on Raspbery pi b+ and both give me this error.

I used to have Arch Linux on my b+ before without any problems!

I have wget 1.17.1

**Edit**

my arch installation is fresh and I ran `pacman -Syu`

**Edit1**

now for some unknown reason wget works on my pi 3 with Ubuntu mate :S weird. my arch Linux on my b+ still gives segmentation fault!

**Edit2**
For some reason it also fixed on my B+ with alarm. I just did nothing in this duration but to run wget again to test it. now it works on both of my raspberry Pies!

Comment: "this" error? Can we assume that the error is what you've placed in the question's title?  It would be best to have it in the body of the question too.  Also, what has ssh got to do with this?  I think you need to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: You should probably try to reinstall wget ubuntu: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --reinstall install wget`.

Comment: WHere is your confusion about ssh being responsible for wget issue coming from I am wondering. There is no mentioning of ssh in your question. Then BAM! "it is ssh's fault". Please try to write your question a little more coherently, supporting your assumptions with what you believe to be true.

Comment: @Julie Pelletier tried that already. It doesn't work :/ I bad the same problem on mate and arch Linux it sounds weird.. Maybe it's a bug with raspberry pi on newer versions of Linux! It used to work on my old arch Installations

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not related to the site you're testing with or the folder you're in?

Comment: @Julie Pelletier I tried several websites Including www.Google.com "that should download the index.HTML AFAIK"

Comment: The error you mentioned in your comment to the answer you got tells us it is related to the output file.  Check that you have write permissions for the current directory or try it in /tmp.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I did a fresh install because I damaged the old one :S think  I damaged my Pi too but anyway on the new install the wget worked the first time. maybe it was a problem with my net?!

Comment: No, it was a file permission issue or something similar.  For the error to be a bit less obvious, I think it was caused by a protection layer (maybe selinux or something similar).

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a segfault issue with 1.17.1. It's caused by a narrow terminal window, specifically with 50 or less "columns" in width, and one workaround includes the `-q` flag. See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=823891

Fixed in 1.18.

Unfortunate, as 1.17 is in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/167906)

Comment: The real solution was included in my answer: upgrade to 1.18. That's it.

Added a bit more about the terminal width: "specifically with 50 or less "columns" in width, and one workaround includes the -q flag".

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose this problem, try running the following command as root:

```
pacman -S gdb && gdb wget
```

Look for any language indicating that there is an error in the output.

Comment: Reading symbols from wget...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
/home/alarm/http://WWW.blah.mp4: No such file or directory

Comment: I ran `gdb wget link ` as normal user !! Gdb without link gave me nothing special

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug affecting lots of distros. It causes the application crash when trying to download large files via HTTP.
You can cross-check it trying to download a large file from an FTP server instead.

I too have had this problem on Ubuntu and I solved it by installing an old Debian package for wget (patched with all security updates necessary. eg: wget 1.13.4-3 + deb7u3) and then I blocked the installation of updates for wget up as the Ubuntu version will not be fixed (using: sudo apt-mark hold packagename).

Comment: I'm getting this with wdel without -q. From a bash script. 18 months later still.

Comment: Getting this with the Fedora FC 37 beta, 2022 wget 1.21.3